# SpringData mongoDB API for Aggregation $map $mergeObjects $filter

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Following is my Native MongoDB query and I try to migrate the SpringData Mongo API equivalent. I am getting struck on using $map $mergeObjects $filter in $project in SpringData Mongo API. Appreciate your help on completing my conversion to API

subset of Native MongoDB:

`{ "$project" : { "queues" : {  "$map" : {  "input" : "$queues",  "as" : "one",  "in" : {  "$mergeObjects" : ["$$one", { "$arrayElemAt" : [{ "$filter" : { "input" : "$interceptionData", "as" : "two", "cond" : { "$eq" : ["$$two.name", "$$one.name"]}}}, 0]}]}}}, "total" : "$total.total"}}`

Spring Query

var projectStage = Aggregation.project().and(VariableOperators.Map.itemsOf("$queues").`as`("one")   ....

I can't migrate the Native MongoDB query to SpringData Mongo API equivalent